# How do I make it so that a rule that an admin in one server doesn't change the rule of another server?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

## Problem: Rule gets rewritten in every server, not just the server it was rewritten in.

### How do I go about fixing this issue?

An example I have is that my friend created a rule, let's say for instance it's: 'Don't mention me'. Sure it changes the rule now and people can now see that the rule is changed but for other servers, their rules will then also change to 'Don't mention me'. That's the issue I am stuck with. I want it so that only the server that the rule was written in sees that change and not any other server.

```
rule_ = 'hi'

@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
@client.command()
async def rulecreate(ctx, *, rule):
    global rule_
    rule_ = rule
    embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Rule(s)', color = discord.Colour.blurple())
    embed.add_field(name = "Question: ", value = rule, inline = False)
    embed.set_footer(icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url, text = f"Requested by {ctx.author.name}")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@client.command()
async def rules(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Rule(s)')
    embed.add_field(name = 'Rule(s)', value = rule_, inline = False)
    embed.set_footer(icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url, text = f"Requested by {ctx.author.name}")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

When using 1 variable to 'persist' the rule you create, the rule will be the same for every guild that instance of your bot is in. When restarting your bot, this rule will be reset to the default 'hi' too.

If you want different rules for different servers, you could save the rules in a json or database for each server using the guild_id as unique identifier for each server.